# Captive Portal Using PHP and iptables Firewall on Linux

Tags: networking, php, iptables, firewall

I am trying to make a captive portal following this [tutorial](https://projectzme.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/captive-portal-using-php-and-iptables-firewall-on-linux/#comment-7746) . I am stuck in this command 
`sudo iptables -t mangle -I internet 1 -m mac --mac-source USER-MAC-ADDRESS-HERE -j RETURN`

Here whose MAC address should be entered. Do we have to enter mac address of all the users who would connect manually (which sounds stupid and i don't think that's possible) or should we enter mac of the server?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is a per user method, so yes one such line per user and their MAC.

Comment: that means i should know which user I want to allow to use internet? Isn't there any other way which captures the mac automatically when they connect to the network and authenticate users based on their records?

Answer (score 0):

That paticutal command is to remove a user already "allowed". This way if you want to remove the so they have to authenticate again you would run that command.